# Sync Framework - Check logic before synchronizing

Tags: azure, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

I'm wondering whether I can sync two databases with some logic.

```
DbSyncTableDescription user = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("User", sqlServerConn);
DbSyncTableDescription role = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Role", sqlServerConn);
DbSyncTableDescription usersInRoles = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("UsersInRoles", sqlServerConn);
```

For example, sync administrators to user table. Do not sync staffs.

[image]

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a filter in your scope... see: [Walkthrough: Defining Filtered Scope and Provisioning Server Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928601.aspx)

or if you want more logic around what needs to be synched, you can intercept the changes in the ChangesSelected event...see: [Manipulating the change dataset in Sync Fx](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/)